# Fiddler not capturing traffic from specific applications

Tags: fiddler

so I got a bit of a weird question. Fiddler captures traffic perfectly with apps like chrome or discord, but when I open a game such as roblox or geometry dash, fiddler does not capture any traffic from these apps. Any way around this or another app that can sniff traffic from apps properly?

Answer (score 1):

Fiddler is a proxy server which, when started, should work without additional configuration with apps that respect the Windows networking configuration.

Some applications are not respecting them though, so if you need to debug their traffic, you should explicitly configure them (if possible at all) to use the Fiddler proxy, which is by default on 127.0.0.1:8888.